# i am facing frozen issue moues and keyboard not working

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, suspend, freeze

I have recently switched to Linux I am facing problems when I use some applications from Snap and other applications my system completely freezes mouse keybord doesn't work I have to shut down the machine and have to start it again. and also the same problem occurs when I suspend my machine.

hardware model: HP Victus by HP Gaming Laptop 15-fb0xxx.
memory: 8 GB.
processor: AMD® Ryzen 5 5600h with Radeon graphics × 12.
graphics: RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-46-gene

Comment: I'm using similar hardware with Kernel 6 and X11 server without problems. Try to switch from Wayland to X11 as first step.